# Delete GWT module development mode?

Tags: gwt, module, development-mode

I have a GWT application with several modules. I have deleted one that I don't need anymore (`JasperReportTest`) - I deleted `JasperReportTest.gwt.xml` file and classes referring to that module.

But when I try to run my application in development mode I get this in my console:

```
Loading modules
com.mycompany.myapp.JasperReportTest
  [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/mycompany/myapp/JasperReportTest.gwt.xml' on 
your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a 
classpath entry for source?
```

If I run compile everything works fine. How can I delete the module, so development mode won't try to load it? I searched project for string "`JasperReportTest`" and I didn't find it. Where is loading of this module written?

Answer (score 1):

Solved - problem was that in Run configurations I had that module in startup command

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Google → Web Toolkit in your project's properties.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same behaviour, and the good place to remove the reference to the unwanted module is in "*run configuration*" dialog but in the "*arguments*" tab', not in GWT one.